# taskdef class org.testng.TestNGAntTask cannot be found

Tags: ant, testng

I'm trying to get ant to compile and keep getting:

> taskdef class org.testng.TestNGAntTask cannot be found

Most examples I see have this in the classpath: `${libs.dir}/testng-6.8.jar`

I also tried:

```
<taskdef name="testng" classpath="${test.classpath}"
    classname="org.testng.TestNGAntTask" />
```

Parts of my build.xml

```
<property environment="env"/>
<property name="ws.home" value="${basedir}"/>
<property name="ws.jars" value="C:\jars"/>
<property name="test.dest" value="${ws.home}/build"/>
<property name="test.src" value="${ws.home}/src"/>
<property name="ng.result" value="test-output"/>


<target name="setClassPath" unless="test.classpath">
    <path id="classpath_jars">
        <fileset dir="${ws.jars}" includes="*.jar"/>
    </path>
    <pathconvert pathsep=":" property="test.classpath" refid="classpath_jars"/>
</target>
```

What path should I use and how do I know what version of `testng.jar` I have

[image]
<sub>Screenshot of my eclipse environment</sub>

If I compile with `-v`, I get:

```
[echo] classpath------: C:\jars\testng.jar
```

I copied `testng.jar` to this directory and still no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the path reference, instead of a property, when creating the task. For example:

```
<path id="classpath_jars">
  <fileset dir="${ws.jars}" includes="*.jar"/>
</path>

<taskdef name="testng" classpathref="classpath_jars" classname="org.testng.TestNGAntTask" />
```

---

## Future consideration

> What path should I use and how do I know what version of testng.jar I
>   have

Have you considered adding Maven style dependency management to your build?
This would give you more certainty about which jars are being used by your build process as you've requested. As it stands, you are relying on manual configuration that the correct jar is placed in the expected directory.

Dependency management is a capability provided by the [Apache ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) plugin. It provides additional tasks that enable you to manage classpaths via jars automatically downloaded and cached from the [Central Maven repository](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.testng%7Ctestng%7C6.11%7Cjar).

For example:

```
 <ivy:cachepath pathid="build.path">
     <dependency org="org.testng" name="testng" rev="6.11" conf="default"/>
 </ivy:cachepath>

 <taskdef name="testng" classpathref="build.path" classname="org.testng.TestNGAntTask" />
```

The following more complete example demonstrates how ANT can be configured to setup the ivy plugin automatically, making your build portable across all machine. All you need is Java and ANT installed.

### build.xml

```
<project name="demo" default="build" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">

    <!--
    ================
    Build properties
    ================
    -->
    <available classname="org.apache.ivy.Main" property="ivy.installed"/> 

    <!--
    ==========
    Build main
    ==========
    -->

    <target name="build" depends="install-ivy">
         <ivy:cachepath pathid="build.path">
             <dependency org="org.testng" name="testng" rev="6.11" conf="default"/>
         </ivy:cachepath>

         <taskdef name="testng" classpathref="build.path" classname="org.testng.TestNGAntTask" />
    </target>

    <!--
    ===========
    Build setup
    ===========
    -->
    <target name="install-ivy" description="Install ivy" unless="ivy.installed">
        <mkdir dir="${user.home}/.ant/lib"/>
        <get dest="${user.home}/.ant/lib/ivy.jar" src="http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/ivy/ivy/2.4.0/ivy-2.4.0.jar"/>
        <fail message="Ivy has been installed. Run the build again"/>
    </target>


</project>
```

Comment: @mark-oconnor thanks for suggestion mark. I'm just learning all this stuff as part of a selenium/testng framework course on udemy, so above is all a bit foreign. I think maven is a section coming up soon

Comment: @mark1234 Maven is a completely different build tool. Maven pioneered the integration of classpath path management into the build process (via the use of remote binary repositories). The ivy plugin effectively retrofits this capability into ANT. I highly recommend considering using it, in the long run much better when compared to manually copying jars around on the developers laptop.

Comment: @mark1234 Revised my answer. I think I discovered the specific problem

Comment: @mark-oconnor thanks update (i gave you upvote and marked as solution as it did help). It seems to have fixed itself somehow. I think I may have not run build before compile after some change. Thanlks for tips on ivy. Will definitely look into Ivy once I've completed my course